# Format Code in Visual Studio Code not working on Mac OS X (El Capitan)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Update:

Not sure what happened to my Visual Studio Code installation, but removing and re-installing the application (via homebrew) fixed the problem. Shift - Option - F once again formats code!

---

I'm struggling to format code in Visual Studio Code on MAC OSX El Capitan.

For some reason the default key binding ('Shift + Option + F') does not work. I also no longer have the option to format code via the 'Command + Shift + P', and entering '>format code'. In fact, '>format code' isn't even an option in the list anymore.

This used to work, but I am not sure what changed.

'Shift + Option + F' does do something though, it makes a ' ̰' character appear that results in some weird cursor behaviour (not sure how else to describe it) when moving over characters adjacent to the ' ̰' character.

Additional information:

- I'm creating an Ember.js (v2.3.0) application
- I've tried formatting *.js, *.hbs and *.json files, but it doesn't work in any of these

Comment: This is happening to me and I reinstalled with no success.  Did the 'format code' option come back in the 'Command + Shift + P', and entering '>format code'?

Comment: Installed this on another machine, same issue.  Maybe this was removed in v 0.10.8?

Comment: still not working for me in 0.10.9

Comment: Same is happening with VS Code 1.0 in April 2016. I am on Yosemite though.

Comment: I haven't had an issue since I uninstalled initially and reinstalled via homebrew. Since then I've been updating via Visual Studio Code directly (when it notifies me of an update). I did the same for the v1.0 update and no issues so far.

Comment: I'm having this issue in v1.5.2 on my Mac, and uninstalling/reinstalling isn't working. Does anyone know what could be causing this? Whenever I use the `shift+option+F` command, it just prints `Ï`, and format isn't an option when using `cmd+shift+P`

Comment: This is happening with the 1.48.2 version (August 25, 2020) on OS X High Sierra (formatting JSON, Python, Java). It seems like OSX is intercepting shift-option-F before VS Code can get it. Using Cmd-Shift-P and selecting ''Format document" works fine

Comment: I have solved this issue in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugMRXHlpJGE

Answer (score 51):

I came from Windows to Mac as a newbie, expecting the most basic things like code formatting would work with Shift+ALt+F as it does on Windows.
But naturally, it didn't. The problem was, Keyboard - Input Source (Default in India - [ABC - India]) doesn't capture Shift+Alt+F, which was evident in the  "Command Palette: Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting"

Solution:

- System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources (tab)
- I had ABC - India (defaulted), needed to remove it and added U.S. International - PC

[image: Screenshot of the keyboard settings on Mac]

Comment: Thanks for the easy solution 

Comment: same situation and this solved my problem as well.

Comment: Never thought this could be this reason. Thanks for saving my day.

Comment: This works, but im facing a strange issue like when i try to enter password on my Teams app, im unable to input special chats like ^

Answer (score 9):

**Solution**

1. Go to the system settings then go to the keyboard section.

> If your input sources are other than ABC (eg ABC - India) that might
> be the source of this issue.

[image: Screenshot 1]

2. Go to edit Input Sources and add a new Input source.

[image: Screenshot 2]

3. Add ABC keyboard Input source.

[image: Screenshot 3]

4. Now remove ABC - India input source.

[image: Screenshot 4]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugMRXHlpJGE

Answer (score 2):

on mac keyboard type US International - PC screws up few characters like the usual shift + 6 "^" is replaced with "ˆ" , i set it to just US from ABC India and it worked fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and realized that there was a fixed for that. VS Code repo has a closed issue for that and this may explain why your issue was fixed after reinstalling.

This is the link for the question on the VS Code repo:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11810

Answer (score 1):

It's happening from time to time in my mac and if I just restart VScode it works again. Give it a try before reinstalling it the next time

Answer (score 1):

If the 'Format Document' shortcut(option+shift+F) is not working on your MAC you can try right-clicking and then using the format document option.

Still,  it is mostly because your text input is set to a different keyboard layout such as British, Indian, etc. You need to change your default to U.S.

To change your text input goes to your mac setting>search keyboard>Text Input>InputSources>Edit>then use + sign to add US layout and use - to remove other ones.

Hope it works fine after that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am glad you were able to solve your own problem!

Often a simple reinstall can fix a lot of odd issues with various programs. Depending on what version you were on, updates can also fix bugs that might have caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. January 2016 Visual Studio Code release had preliminary support for Salsa. In order to use that you had to install Typescript 1.8 and add typescript.tsdk setting like:

`// Specifies the folder path containing the tsserver and lib*.d.ts files to use.
"typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"`

February 2016 Visual Studio Code release does not need that anymore as Salsa is default anyway. Removing typescript.tsdk setting enabled code format functionality again for me.